# Should the CSS property list-style be applied to <ul>/<ol> or <li>?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Most sites show the syntax as applying `list-style` to the `<li>` but I've seen some tutorial sites (like [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_list-style.asp)) that apply `list-style` to the `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Which is the 'correct' way?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to the W3C CSS2 reference, which can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style),

> Another solution would be to specify 'list-style' information only on the list type elements:
>
> ```
> ol.alpha  { list-style-type: lower-alpha }
> ul        { list-style-type: disc }
> ```
>
> Inheritance will transfer the 'list-style' values from OL and UL elements to LI elements. This is the recommended way to specify list style information.

So you can do it at the overall list level if all of your elements are going to be the same, but you can instead do it at the list entry level if for example some entries would have different glyphs (like a square instead of a disc) to convey some meaning. You can also do *both*, with the list level style serving as a default to be overridden (but be careful about selector precedence!).

Comment: hence the "cascade" in CSS

Comment: *Not* hence the "cascade". It says right there in the quote that it's "inheritance". They both play a part in style resolution but are two totally different things.

Answer (score 1):

As not having a list style is generally more common that having a list style, I personally apply it to both in a global reset at the top of my stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The spec recommends that you that you set it on `<ul>` and `<ol>` tags, and not on `<li>`.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#list-style

Comment: CSS1 was already obsolete for a good number of years at the time this answer was posted. Avoid citing CSS1 unless for historical reasons - it is recommended to cite CSS2.1 instead (which for that matter had already been done *two years ago* at the time this was posted).